# how to declare C array of volatile struct

Tags: c

I defined a struct and I do not want to put the volatile into the struct because other instance may not need it (e.g. RAM caching).
Now I need that a particular array of this struct be volatile.

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t rxPacket[FIFO_SIZE];
    uint8_t length;
    int8_t rssi;
    uint8_t lqi;
}rawRx_t;
```

Is this the right way to have each (struct) element of the array volatile ?

```
static volatile rawRx_t rawRxBuffer[NB_MAX_RX_FRAME];
```

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Paring it down and switching the type to something [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) can parse, we get:

```
volatile int rawRxBuffer[];
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
declare rawRxBuffer as array of volatile int
```

the point is that it's an "array of volatile", i.e. each array element is volatile.